# MeteorJS what to put under /server folder?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm following the Discover Meteor book and the book suggets put js file under /collections folder. The js file defines server side methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
  post: function(postAttributes) {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({url: postAttributes.url});

    // ensure the user is logged in
    if (!user)
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new stories");

    // ensure the post has a title
    if (!postAttributes.title)
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a headline');

    // check that there are no previous posts with the same link
    if (postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(302, 
        'This link has already been posted', 
        postWithSameLink._id);
    }

    // pick out the whitelisted keys
    var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), {
      userId: user._id, 
      author: user.username, 
      submitted: new Date().getTime(),
      commentsCount: 0,
      upvoters: [],
      votes: 0
    });

    var postId = Posts.insert(post);
    return postId;
  },
});
```

Well, in that case, isn't the whole logic accessible to public since `Meteor gathers all JavaScript files in your tree, with the exception of the server, public, and private subdirectories, for the client.`?

Is this a concern?
What should I put to `server` folder?

Comment: Any code in the `server/` folder can not use latency compensation. Methods defined on the client will be run as method *stubs*, which are client-side simulations that can greatly improve the apparent speed of your application, and then be overridden when the server eventually responds. Similarly, things like allow/deny rules can be defined on the client as well as the server to enable latency compensation. Thus, for optimal performance, the only code that should go in `server/` should be code that can not or should not (e.g. for security concerns) be subject to latency compensation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many server-only things that might go in that folder – subscriptions, allow rules, cron jobs etc.

The `server` folder is the only place from which your code is not visible to general public. Naturally, it's the place where you should put your security-related code: allow / deny rules, accounts configuration etc. If you talk to an external API and want to place your access keys in code, /server folder is the only acceptable place to do so.

Putting your server-side logic in an accessible folder is not a critical issue, as server-side code cannot be altered from the client. The only security concern here is that someone might study your code and find a breech if you did a shortcut somewhere. Also, you're clogging the connection with code that's not needed in the client.

I'd also say that most methods should go in /server, but that depends on what you need. Making methods code accessible on the client allows to take advantage of latency compensation ([here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods), third paragraph below the example), but you need to make sure yourself that the client-side simulation doesn't produce side effects that would interfere with the actual (server-side) modifications.

In your case, you can put this method in /collections or /model folder and don't worry about this. You can also put it in /server and things will work as well.